# Will installing Softwares like Apache server as part of WAMP create a loopback interface in Windows?

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, apache-http-server, wamp

Linux has lo interface where you can configure loopback interfaces for your testing purposes I assume, is that how when you install softwares that simulate a server communicate through?

Comment: If you install e.g XAMPP from Apache, you will have a server address of `localhost` which maps to IP address `127.0.0.1` I.e, your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

> Will installing Softwares like Apache server as part of WAMP create a loopback interface in Windows?

No. Windows already has a hidden loopback interface where the usual "localhost" addresses (127.0.0.1 and ::1) are handled. Accessing your website at `http://localhost` does not require any special setup – it's a basic feature that's already present on any OS.

> is that how when you install softwares that simulate a server communicate through?

WAMP / XAMPP don't really "simulate" a server, they install actual server software – they bundle the exact same Apache HTTP Server that is used on many websites.